# What event to use to capture change in a cell and log into another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have written code under onEdit(event ) trigger to copy the particular cell/cells  content  of one of the column  of Sheet "A"to another sheets "B" cell/cells.
(Note :the cells of sheet A gets updated by formulae which is on another set of column cells within same sheet "A")
The triggers works when I manually pdate the cells on sheet "A".But it dont work if formulae updates those cells.`enter code here`
Anything I am missing or using wrong trigger ?

```
function onChange(event) 
{
    var sheet = event.range.getSheet();

     if(sheet.getName() == "Today"){

    var cellRange = event.range;

    var cellColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
    var cellValue = event.value;

    if (cellColumn == 13) {
      // correct column

       var name = cellRange.offset(0,-12).getValue(); 
      // get name, 12 column to left
      var time = new Date();                   // timestamp

      var active_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var output_Log_sheet = active_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Logs");
      output_Log_sheet.appendRow([cell.getA1Notation(),name ,cell.getValue() + "  ",time]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's normal behavior. 
From the documentation onOpen(e) runs **when a user opens** a spreadsheet, document, or form that he or she has permission to edit.
onEdit(e) runs **when a user changes** a value in a spreadsheet.
onInstall(e) runs **when a user installs** an add-on.

Comment: Ok.So OnEdit() trigger run only ,if user update something in the cell.What if formula update that particular cell.which trigger to use ?

Comment: There's no trigger for that.  You would have to sample it periodically with a timebased trigger.